# Checking Controls in multiple panels

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a programs with multiple panels with textboxes that will share a value. for example a street address. I have coded a way for these values to be updated by sharing a `TextChanged` event, however the event does not search the panels for the controls, it will only affect a `TextBox` in the main form window.

Code.

```
private void matchtextbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox objTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
    string textchange = objTextBox.Text;           

    foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
    {
        if (x is TextBox)
        {
            if (((TextBox)x).Name.Contains("textBoxAddress"))
            {
                ((TextBox)x).Text = textchange;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So say `panel1` contains `textBoxAddress1`, `panel` contains `textBoxAddress2`, both with this `TextChanged` event. they do not update each other when typing. However if they are outside the `panel` they do.

Final Code which is the resolution based on a lovely community member below.

```
private void Recursive(Control.ControlCollection ctrls)
{
    foreach (var item in ctrls)
    {
        if (item is Panel)
        {
            Recursive(((Panel)item).Controls);
        }
        else if (item is TextBox)
        {
            if (((TextBox)item).Name.Contains("txtSAI"))
            {
                ((TextBox)item).Text = textchange;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void matchtextbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox objTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
    textchange = objTextBox.Text;  
    Recursive(Controls);
}

string textchange;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) method for this purpose:

```
private void Recursive(IEnumerable ctrls)
{
    foreach (var item in ctrls)
    {
        if (item is Panel)
        {
            Recursive(((Panel)item).Controls);
        }
        else if(item is TextBox)
        {
            if (((TextBox)item).Name.Contains("textBoxAddress"))
            {
                ((TextBox)item).Text = textchange;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
private void matchtextbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Recursive(Controls);
}
```