# Set multiple TextBoxes editable after button click on WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I have set all my `TextBoxs.readOnly = true;` in the form by default.
But when an `Edit Button` is clicked.
I want it to make all the `TextBoxs.readOnly = false;`

I have tried;

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var textBox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        textBox.ReadOnly = false;
}
```

Each `TextBox` has a unique name.
The easiest way to do it would be this, below. But I don't want to do it that way.

```
txtName.ReadOnly = false;
txtAddress.ReadOnly = false;
...
```

Comment: With this approach you can set just `TextBoxes` that are placed directly in your form not those that are inside another container like `GroupBox` or `Panel`. You need a recursive method for this purpose see here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/34676012/2946329

Comment: all the `TextBoxes` are inside a `GroupBox`

Comment: @user2946329 is right, but I'd prefer either [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3426721/1997232) recursive method or simply hold controls references in dedicated array. If controls are inside same container, then replace `this` with that container instance (in your case that `GroupBox`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this approach you can set just `TextBoxes`'s `ReadOnly` that are placed directly in your form not those that are inside another container like `GroupBox` or `Panel`. You need a [`recursive`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) method for this purpose if you have more than one container ([`example1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34676012/2946329), [`example2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3426721/2946329)). But Since all your `TextBoxes` are inside one `GroupBox` then simply replace `this` with your `GroupBox`'s `Name` like this:

```
foreach (var textBox in groupBox1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    textBox.ReadOnly = false;
```