# Check if any textbox is empty and fill it with a value

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void btnSaveInformation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control child in Controls)
        {
            if (child is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox tb = child as TextBox;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
                {
                    tb.Text = @"N/A";
                }
            }
        }
        //var bal = new StudentBal
        //{
        //    FirstName = txtFirstName.Text
        //};
        //bal.InsertStudent(bal);
    }
```

What I want to achieve is for the system to check if there is any blank checkbox, and I have numerous in the form, and if it is blank, then assign a value of "N/A". What am I doing wrong with the codeI have? Thank you.

Comment: have you tried `TextBox tb = (TextBox)child;`

Comment: Nothing wrong. Are your text boxes inside other controls like group boxes or panels?

Comment: Oh. it is inside a group box. What should be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set multiple TextBoxes editable after button click on WinForm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743783/set-multiple-textboxes-editable-after-button-click-on-winform)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the textboxes placed in panels or other grouping controls?  If so, the form's Controls collection would not contain references to them; they would only contain the immediate children (which would be the panels, etc.)

If they are contained within a group control or panel, you would want to do something like this instead:

```
foreach (Control child in myGroupPanel.Controls)
{
    if (child is TextBox) { // your additional code here }
}
```

If you want a more robust method, the following show different ways of getting a list of all controls:

[How to get all children of a parent control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595425/how-to-get-all-children-of-a-parent-control)

[How to get ALL child controls of a Windows Forms form of a specific type (Button/Textbox)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button)

Comment: The textboxes are in one group box but in different panels. I tried your suggestion but still no ace.

Comment: The quick and dirty solution is to identify the immediate parents of the textboxes and create a concatenated list you can loop through.  You can use LINQ's Concat for this: var controls = panel1.Controls.Concat(panel2.Controls).Concat(panel3.Controls).Concat(...); foreach(Control child in controls) { ... }.  This is quick and dirty though and isn't scalable once you start adding more text boxes.  In that scenario, you would want something like those in the links I added.

Comment: Okay Nailbite. Thanks! I'll study the links you provided. It's gonna be abit hard since I don't know LINQ yet

Answer (score 0):

You could use `child.GetType()` to get the type of the control while iterating the group of controls, then compare the same with the `typeof(TextBox)` with will help you to filter textBoxes from the control collection. try this:

```
foreach (Control child in Controls)
{
    if (child.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)child;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
        {
            tb.Text = @"N/A";
        }
    }
}
```

Or else you can use iterate through filtered collection like the following(assuming that `Controls` is a collection of controls):

```
foreach (Control child in Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList())
{
     TextBox tb = (TextBox)child;
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
     {
         tb.Text = @"N/A";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong in your code. I suspect controls that you are looking are nested controls.

I would suggest flatten the hierarchy and get all the (nested)controls and then look for specific type.

```
static Func<Control, IEnumerable<Control>> GetControls =
        (control) => control
            .Controls
            .Cast<Control>().SelectMany(x => GetControls(x))
            .Concat(control.Controls.Cast<Control>());
```

Now you could use the above delegate in your code like shown below.

```
foreach (TextBox tb in  GetControls(this).OfType<TextBox>())
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
    {
        tb.Text = @"N/A";
    }
}
```